# Testing React Components which Display Other Components in Loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm working on a react-native app. There's a simple component that gets an array and shows it as markers on a map with react-native-maps.

I'm trying to test the component. In the test I want to check that there's a marker for every element of an array.

However, I'm getting this error:

```
    console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
      Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

      Check the render method of `Places`.
          in Places
    console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2053
      The above error occurred in the  component:
          in MapView (created by Places)
          in Places

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      You can learn more about error boundaries at https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html.

  ● shows a marker for each place

    Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

    Check the render method of `Places`
```

**Here is my code**

**Places.js**

```jsx
export default class Places extends Component<{}> {
  //constructor

  render() {
    return (
      <MapView style={styles.container}
        initialRegion={this.state.initialRegion}
      >
        {this.props.places.map(place => (
          <MapView.Marker
            key={place.id}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: place.location.lat,
              longitude: place.location.lng
            }}
            title={place.name}
          />
        ))}
      </MapView >
    );
  }
}
```

**__tests__/Places.js**

```js
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import Places from '../../src/places/Places'

import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.mock('react-native-maps', () => 'MapView');

it('shows a marker for each place', () => {
  const places = [
    { id: 1, name: 'test', location: { lat: 1, lng: 2 } }
  ];

  const testee = renderer.create(
    <Places places={places} />
  );
  
  //not even having any expect statements yet
});
```

I'm pretty much sure I'm doing something silly, however I cannot find examples of the internet of testing such components.

Comment: Try `console.log` `MapView` and `MapView.Marker` inside `render()`. Their value might be `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by using [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme)

```js
it('shows a place component for each place', () => {
  const testee = shallow(
    <Places places={places} />
  );

  const placeComponents = testee.find('Place');

  expect(placeComponents.length).toEqual(places.length);

  placeComponents.forEach((placeComponent, index) => {
        expect(placeComponent.prop('place')).toEqual(places[index]);
  });
});
```